# Getting plink ssh to execute a command in the background on target machine with password

Tags: linux, ssh, tty, plink

I'm having a problem where I try and run a command in Plink with the -ssh flag and -t flag (i'm using sudo) but when the service (dmf) is started and the tty is killed (obviously because it is when plink finishes), then the service dies as well. I need a way to detach the command but also be able to enter the password for sudo as well...

So far I have this which starts the service then the service dies after plink detaches after execution.

```
D:\bin\x64\Debug>plink.exe -ssh -t -pw Password1 admin@10.12.12.42 "echo -e Password1\n | sudo -S service dmf start"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: I am not allowed to change any file on the box i.e. sudoers file, or sudo visudo etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to restart service:

```
plink.exe -pw yourpassword -t login@example.com sudo **-b** service karaf start
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `-t` try `-tt` to "force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty".

Comment: Also after connection close, service still dies.

Comment: Okay.  I'm not familiar with that specific ssh client, but thought it was worth a try. I've had success applying `-tt` when experiencing similar problems.

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately with just using ssh and entering prompted password, the -tt doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [`nohub`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) and add a `&` in the part of your command that gets executed on the server, like this: `D:\bin\x64\Debug>plink.exe -ssh -t -pw Password1 admin@10.12.12.42 "echo -e Password1\n | sudo -S nohub service dmf start &"`

That should make it start in the background and ignore you logging out.

Comment: Password prompt appears and without me typing this is what happens:

Comment: D:\bin\x64\Debug>plink.exe -ssh -t -pw Password1 admin@10.12.12.42 "echo -e Password1\n | sudo -S nohub service dmf stop"

[sudo] password for admin: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for admin:
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt

Comment: Maybe `nohub sudo`.  Did you remember the trailing `&`?.  Sorry, I'm out of ideas.  But when I think of it, I find it weird that your session has to keep running in order to start a service -- though the `service` command, mind you.  I would expect `service` to keep running for as long as it takes for the service to start and then return.  I could be wrong, though. For the 3rd time ;)

Comment: "echo -e Password1\n | nohub sudo -S service dmf stop", renders a "bash: nohub: command not found :(. It is weird but i'm sure there is a work around for this. Using "sudo -b" does the job of putting the process in the background and it continues to run after the session dies which is good, but this is assuming we enter the password. Just need to get the password to be put in somehow :(

Comment: Are you able to place your server-side commands in a script on the server?  Breaking up the tasks could make things easier.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to place anything on the server. Has to be stop service, start service, leave... all remotely.

Comment: It may be worth finding out if `nohub` is even available on the server.

Comment: The command you are looking for it's `nohup`  with a P not a B. Regards.

Comment: Useful tip indeed =)